# Git Commit Message Linting as a gateway and not after it was already pushed

Tags: git, github, devops, github-api, githooks

I want to verify a specific commit message structure across organisation, I want it to not be possible to merge/push to master/main commits **unless the message fits a very certain format**.

Commit message is linting is covered via a simple regular expression, expected format is something like:

```
\[[A-Z]{2}-(\d){5,7}\]\-(.|\r|\n)*
```

Adding commits to master/main happens in few ways:

1. Commit locally on master, push to remote.
2. Commit locally on branch, merge locally to master, push to remote.
3. Commit locally to branch, open pull request (case of github) *merge PR from the github UI*.

I can easily cover the case of #1 with a *git-commit* hook, to cover both 2 and 3, I can use a CI hook, but this will *AFTER the fact* e.g. at this point fixing the commit format is too late.

For 2, I can probably also add a a *pre-push hook*, but for 3, given that the operation happens on the server side I can't seem to find a straight forward solution that will not execute the linting process after the commit is already on the master/main branch.

Comment: Why is the CI hook for 3 too late? Don't you have any pipeline that runs on the PR prior to merging?

Comment: CI Hook is too late because it's after the merge to master is done via PR merge. Running this on the branch is possible but very problematic because I don't want to fail tests of branch CI just because a commit message is incorrect. I don't care about the branch commits, I want the developers to figure out the perfect commit message only once - before merging/pushing to master.

Comment: I mean run it _only on the PR_, so they have to choose an appropriate message when opening the PR, not necessarily when working on a branch. You haven't told us what and why the format is and what the CI currently does, so it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think the format is important I'll add an example of it. The work on the branch is always very dynamic. Multiple commits, open a PR, sometimes before and sometimes after squashing all the commits, then fix PR comments, and only a the end of that, which may span ~50 commits, merge to master in and single and squashed. So linting during that fast review&fix cycles on the finalised commit message is way too early and will disturb the flow.

Comment: if you control the server, the `pre-receive` hook is the one you'd use to vet pushes.  all other hooks that you mentioned (`commit-msg`, `pre-commit`, `pre-push`) are client hooks and can be bypassed

Comment: Right, But on github (non-enterprise), where git is a SaaS, I can not control pre-receive hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this with a repository on GitHub is to use a CI job for this, possibly using a bot to do the merge if necessary.  The only two places you can effectively impose any control on a repository are in a `pre-receive` hook and a CI system, and GitHub does not allow you to custom the `pre-receive` hook beyond the configuration in your repository.

Using a hook on the user side is easy to bypass and isn't an effective control.  So if you care about the commit message, then the only place you can control it is using CI.  The [Git FAQ explains why this is the case](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusehookstopreventusersfrommakingcertainchanges).

You should protect your main branch using the GitHub settings for that and set the option “Require status checks to pass before merging.”  That means that people will either need to put their changes in a PR and pass your CI checks before merging, or push the commit they want to push to the main branch to a temporary branch, then fast-forward the main branch once the CI checks pass.

If you want the merge message to also contain a specific string, then you need to have a bot do all PR merges and be responsible for the merge, since you can't check the merge message through a CI check before it happens.

There aren't any other effective solutions to this problem: the alternatives can either be bypassed trivially or just aren't effective.  It isn't exceptionally burdensome to require people to format their commit messages in a certain way, even when working on an in-progress PR.  I've worked at jobs where this was the policy and it wasn't a problem.

Comment: I tend to somewhat disagree, commit linting on the branch level is straightforward at times, but, is very much dependent on the nature of a branch. In some cases, branches are an exploratory ground and getting CI failures due to some specific rule on the commit message will be very frustrating.
With that in mind, your answer is the sad truth. it is not really possible in a cleaner way.
The solution I have found is a bit different, use github API to loop over org repos and monitor new commits to master +  alert on violations. This is a form of after the fact education.